# Custom ip lookup for http with proxy

Tags: http, go, dns

I'm trying to make http request through proxy, the server uses CDN, so the server IP looks different at different places. For testing, I need to send request to some specified server ip.

Currently this is done by sending request to ip address instead of domain, and set `req.Host` to the domain, it works but confusing, is there any Go way of doing this? (like a custom DNS lookup)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func HttpReq(
    method, host, url_, proxyAddr string,
) ([]byte, error) {
    var client *http.Client

    proxy, e := url.Parse(proxyAddr)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }
    netTransport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxy),
    }

    client = &http.Client{Transport: netTransport}

    req, e := http.NewRequest(method, host+url_, nil)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }

    req.Host = "neverssl.com" // <----- the "Host" value in http header

    resp, e := client.Do(req)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, e := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }

    return body, nil
}

func main() {
    //host := "http://18.65.145.83"
    //host := "http://18.65.145.39"
    //host := "http://18.65.145.183"
    host := "http://18.65.145.96"
    url := "/"

    proxyAddr := "socks5://127.0.0.1:3425"

    body, e := HttpReq(`GET`, host, url, proxyAddr)
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for. A Go way of doing what, exactly?

Comment: @Flimzy Like a param `CustomDnsMap` or some  helper function to provide a custom dns ip binding. By "Go way" I mean param or function which are aimed for doing this.

Comment: @aj3423 your approach already the correct one, and in my opinion it's not confusing. the very same approach is also used on other case, such as configuring reverse proxy

Comment: @novalagung what if I trying to use https instead of http?